# Inserting data from one column into end of another, excluding part of the insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, I am trying to insert the data from one column (website URLs) into another column (search terms), without messing up the data already in the inserted column, so I want the data inserted into the end. However, I also want to remove part of the inserted data.

So, the table name is "listings" and the table is currently like this:
[image]

And I want the table to be like this:
[image]

Now, the difficulty is I'm not sure how to remove the possible http:// and or https:// (or any trailing slashs (http:test.com/), I would also need a comma before the domain, so "https://dog.com" would be inserted like ", dog.com"

I know I can do this, but the rest I'm really struggling with.

```
INSERT INTO listings (search_text) SELECT www FROM listings;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `UPDATE` the table, not `INSERT` new rows.
It can be done with [`TRIM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
update listings
set search_text = concat(
  search_text,
  ',',
  trim('/' from trim(leading 'http:' from trim(leading 'https:' from www)))  
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRWazPKaCeyKL6gy6cBmgk/3).
Results:

```
| www              | search_text                     |
| ---------------- | ------------------------------- |
| http://test.com/ | address,city,state,zip,test.com |
| https://one.com/ | address,city,state,zip,one.com  |
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wouldn't have been able to get this right! Much appreciated.